# How do I archive the installers of our application releases correctly?

Tags: artifactory

we have a branded application and our CI pipeline generates a different installer for each branding.

Now to no longer clutter up our CI server we want to deploy the installers for each release build to artifactory.

The problem is that I don't have any idea how to do this properly.

The installers are not maven artifacts or packages in the sense that anything will ever use them as dependencies. They are either *.exe files or *.zip files that the end user can install on their machines.

We want to categorize them by release name (e.g. 2020_09 for the September release of 2020), build number, branding and date of the build.

So the installer for the unicorn branding of the 2020_09 release might be an *.exe file built by build number 3 on August 23rd and the installer for the phoenix branding of the 2020_09 release might be a *.zip file built by build number 2 on August 28th.

How would I deploy those to artifactory with the required metadata from our build server?
Deploying this as a maven artifact of type exe with a groupId, artifactId and version feels wrong and doesn't really fit our needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Generic repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-GenericRepositories) for managing your installer artifacts.
Generic repositories allows you to manage any type of artifact without conforming to certain layouts or other constraints that are enforced by certain package managers.
Artifacts can be deployed to generic repositories using the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact), JFrog [CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) or [CI integrations](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Build+Integration). All 3 options allows you to annotate the artifact with queryable [properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution) as well as capture additional build metadata as part of your build process and deploy it to Artifactory

For the installers versioning you can use:

1. Artifact name - include the version as part of the artifact name, for example `foo-1.1.0.exe`
2. Path - include the version as part of the path `/foo/1.1.0/foo.exe`
3. Properties - annotate the artifact with a `version` property which contains the version. This allows you for example to query for the [latest](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties) version based on the property
4. Any combination of the above

Using a custom [repository layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts), you can gain additional capabilities such as automatic snapshot/integration versions cleanup and deleting old versions.

You can read more about structuring and naming repositories in the [Best Practices for Structuring and Naming Artifactory Repositories](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/) white paper

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer! Unfortunately our artifactory admin is currently on vacation, so I can't test this out and verify your answer, but I'll definitely get back to you and accept the answer once I get this working.